# AppleScript: Breaking up 40 paragraphs into 10 paragraphs of 4 paragraphs

Tags: string, text, applescript, paragraph

Essentially, I am taking a column of data from an excel file and breaking it up into small groups. So:

10

20

30

40

50

60

etc...

broken up into:

"10, 20, 30, 40"

"50, 60, 70, 80"

etc

Using AppleScript, I assume you would nest loops, something along the lines of:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
set theText to text of front document as string
set myParas to every paragraph of theText
set myNum to the number of paragraphs of theText

repeat myNum times

    repeat 4 times

    end repeat

 end repeat
end tell
```

I'm going to be updating data once a month that comes through as a column of numbers and text. I can strip out all the text easy enough, just would like to know the principle of how to break up or merge the paragraphs into smaller blocks.

For many complicated reasons, I am stuck with AppleScript and textEdit, so other alternates (such as massaging with javascript or textWrangler or whatever) is not an option.

Also, maybe textEdit can do this on it's own but the script I will be using will have lots of other operations based on the above result, so AppleScript has to do all the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the step size in a repeat loop, so you could do something like:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to set theText to text of front document
set paras to paragraphs of theText
set step to 4 -- number of items in a group
repeat with i from 1 to (count paras) by step
    try
        buildString(items i thru (i + step - 1) of paras)
    on error errmess number errnum -- index out of bounds
        log errmess
        if errnum is -128 then error number -128 -- quit
        buildString(items i thru -1 of paras) -- just to the end
    end try
end repeat

to buildString(someList)
    set tempTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
    set output to someList as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tempTID
    display dialog output -- show it
    return output
end buildString
```

Comment: That's looking promising. In the console I'm seeing a bunch of output like "(\*55, 135, 166, 294*)
(\*61, 145, 174, 318*)
(\*67, 155, 188, 339*)
(\*73, 168, 197, 363*)
(\*81, 173, 207, 378*)
(\*89, 179, 216, 387*)
(\*96, 186, 231, 416*)
(\*102, 191, 231, 412*)
(\*109, 199, 240, 435*)
(\*+109, 220, 264, 484*)" so I assume that's some sort of log output. How do I output that in a string, like 55, 135, 166, 294 \
61, 145, 174, 318 etc

Comment: Yes, those are just log entries of the list items.  `display dialog` doesn't have a whole lot of room, what are you wanting to do with the paragraphs?

Comment: I'm outputting a javascript object, so the final state of the string will be something like: "{ "record": "ms55", "snatch": "135*", "cj": "166", "value": "294" }," with each row of 4 numbers being output as a separate object in an array. Once I get the values, such as "55. 135,166, 294" I can run it through another loop to insert the other bits of text to create the final string.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include using AppleScript's text item delimiters to join list items into a string.

Comment: Thank you. That's great. Starting to see a useable output. How do I save each output from buildString in a variable, so I end up with something to copy to the clipboard or insert into a document? So each output followed by a return like: 55, 135, 166, 294 (return here)  61, 145, 174, 318 (return here) 67, 155, 188, 339 (etc) I've tried concating it in both "to buildString" and in the repeat try loop but no happiness.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your workflow looks like, but a few possibilities would be to build a list of lists to pass on to whatever routine you are using, or maybe have the `buildString` handler call it or copy items to the clipboard.

Comment: Great. Thanks so much for your help. This will make a monthly chore a breeze.

Comment: _"I'm outputting a javascript object, ..."_  How come you don't use JavaScript for the whole process ? Rather than having to go through the many complicated reasons, what are a two big reasons that preclude this ? Even if you are stuck with AppleScript, are you aware you can write an AppleScript using JavaScript [for Automation] (also know as JXA) ? For all intents and purposes, it can do everything AppleScript can do whilst also having the power of JavaScript methods not available to regular AppleScript, such as `map`, `reduce`, etc., which makes all of this a doddle.